# OnFailure Method allways called when using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

A post to the server returns the JSON below

```
{
    "response":{
        "id":20,
        "firstname":"name",
        "lastname":"name",
        "email":"email",
        "gender":"male"
    },
    "status":"CREATED",
    "message":"Success",
    "error":null
}
```

I am unable to parse this result from within my native android app using retrofit, the `onFailure` method of Retrofit is always called, I am sure the request gets to the server because an email is sent to the email address in the JSON above.

I make a call to the server using this method

```
private void pushRegDetailsToServer(RegistrationDetails newRegistration){
    RegistrationService registrationService = ServiceBuilder.builderService(RegistrationService.class);
    Call<Registration> createRequest = registrationService.registerUser(newRegistration);

    createRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Registration>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Registration> call, Response<Registration> response) {
            Response obj = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getResponse();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Registration> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.registration_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my registration service

```
@POST("register")
Call<Registration> registerUser(@Body RegistrationDetails registration);
```

Here is my registration class please note this class has the appropriate setter and getter methods

```
public class Registration {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private Response response;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("error")
    private String error;

}
```

This is my response class

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

}
```

Comment: What does the `throwable` inside the `onFailure` method say?

Comment: Log the error message with `Log.e("ERROR", t);` inside `onFailure()` method instead of showing simple Toast. After that [edit] the question and add stack trace here.